# SailsJS - How to render views in server

Tags: node.js, render, sails.js, viewrendering

Can please someone let me know how to render all the views in the server and send it to the web browser ? Just like any other PHP framework would do ?

Is this feasible at all ?

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "ALL" views? As display_name says the view gets rendered on the server before send to client browser.

Comment: These are interesting example projects: https://github.com/AngelMunoz/sails-nuxt and https://github.com/RasCarlito/sails-hook-next

Answer (score 1):

Read through the [Sails.js documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation).

In the [controllers section](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers) you can learn about the *Response Object*. On the response object you have a function called `view()`.

So you can use `res.view()` to render a view and send it to the client. Typical example:

```
functionNameHere: function(req, res, next) {
    res.view({
        data: {first: "one", second: "two"}
    });
}
```

Sails.js is built on top of Express.js. There are already plenty of tutorials on how to use Express on the internet.

Here is the [documentation for Express](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html).

Comment: The views are rendered on server side, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, the view is rendered server side. If you use a templating engine, like EJS for example, the view will first be rendered, then sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Just put:

```
YourFunctionName : function (req,res) {
    res.view('yourview', option, data);
}
```

The parameters are optional depending on the way you need and you put your route.js file.

Read the controllers section on: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers